# Async.eachSeries: Callback already called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async.js

This is a little long and messy code, but please bear with me because I need to get this done.

I am trying to update a json object in for each users. I want the loop iterations to wait for the asynchronous process to end in order to avoid race conditions. However, this has led to a callback hell and now I cannot decide what is the right place for each callbacks to be returned.

I referred to this answer on Nesting [async.eachSeries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712826/8515731) and also tried to structure my code according to it. But still it does not work. The code gives callback already called error at callback1().

```
    async.eachOfSeries(res, function (value, camp, callback3) {
let _id = res[camp]._id;
let arr = res[camp].campaignID;
async.eachOfSeries(arr, function2, function (err) {
    callback3();
})


function function2(value1, i, callback2) {
    let users = arr[i].users;
    let id = arr[i].id;
    let loop = Math.ceil(users / 1000);
    let limit = 0,
        offset = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < loop; j++) {
        if (users > 1000) {
            limit = 1000;
            users -= limit;
        } else {
            limit = users;
        }
        console.log(limit + " limit " + offset + " offset");
        var start = Date.now();
        while (Date.now() < start + 100) {}
        const request = mailjet
            .get("messagesentstatistics")
            .request({
                "CampaignID": id,
                "AllMessages": true,
                "Limit": limit,
                "Offset": offset
            })
        request
            .then((result) => {
                let data = result.body.Data;
                var loop = 0;
                async.eachOfSeries(data, function1, function (err) {
                    console.log("function");
                    callback2();
                })
                console.log("oooooo");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        offset += limit;
    }

    function function1(value2, val, callback1) {
        console.log(data +" data");
        let jsonObj = data[val];
        let email = jsonObj.ToEmail;
        jsonObj['retailer'] = res[camp].retailer;
        jsonObj['summary'] = 'f';
        let tempObj = {};
        tempObj[id] = jsonObj;
        let options = {
            new: true
        };
        let campId = id;
        User.addCampaignResponse(email, campId, tempObj, options, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                console.log("aasd");
                Campaign.updateResponse(_id, function (err, results2) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    else {
                        console.log("asdasaadas");
                        callback1();
                    }
                }) // console.log(results);
            }
        })
    }

}

}, function (err) {
    callback(undefined, "doneeeeee");
})
```

Is there a better way than this? Can I use waterfall too somewhere? Can I change the callback positions to avoid the error?

---

**EDIT: Simplified code**

```
function function2(value1, i, callback2) {
    // ...
    const request = mailjet
                    .get("messagesentstatistics")
                    .request({
                       // ...
                    });
    request
       .then((result) => {
          // ...
          async.eachOfSeries(data, function1, function (err) {
            callback2();
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // ...
        });
    }
```

---

```
function function1(value2, val, callback1) {
  // ...
  User.addCampaignResponse(email, campId, tempObj, options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      Campaign.updateResponse(_id, function (err, results2) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else callback1();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
async.eachOfSeries(res, function (value, camp, callback3) {
    // ...

    async.eachOfSeries(arr, function2, function (err) {
      callback3();
    });

  },
  function (err) {
    callback(undefined, "doneeeeee");
  });
```

Comment: `var start = Date.now(); while (Date.now() < start + 100) {}` -- okay, I just have to ask. Why?

Comment: For readability it would help a lot if you used named functions instead of anonymous functions.

Comment: If you want to sort it out, first change the code by putting some part into functions, it will be easier to read and so understand and debug

Comment: Because, too many requests in a time period was causing some issues. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @MisterKartoot there are plenty of better solutions for throttling than synchronously blocking the thread...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I will change that as soon as I get this code working :)

Comment: @MaartenBicknese I am afraid I cannot think of way to reorganise the code as it is a nested loop and segregating into different functions won't be possible.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I am afraid I cannot think of way to reorganise the code as it is a nested loop and segregating into different functions won't be possible.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT makes a good point about pulling some of the functionality to their own sections. Your code seems be doing a lot of looping and is very complex so I'm not sure exactly what it does. I have however rewritten some of it to show how you could restructure it into separate functions: here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/sellomkantjwa/92e385341a08c3b668ec0e870371d6c8)

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa This really helped, thank you so much. I'll used this code so that people can follow.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese does this refactoring help?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT does this refactoring help?

Comment: Well obviously `callback2()` is getting called multiple times here - you placed it in a loop! Tip: avoid using `async.js` completely and work only with promises.

Comment: @MisterKartoot Yes it does, i'll post a refactoring based on yours to help people to get your problem

Comment: @Bergi It is not inside the loop, it is inside the final function

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Thanks for the refactoring. Do you know now what is causing the error?

Comment: @MisterKartoot What do you mean by "final function"? I can clearly see a `for (let j = 0; j < loop; j++) {` loop around the callback call.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, I get. But I also get an error for callback already called for callback1(). Why so?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

We use `if (err) return callback(err);` to stop the current async function and send the error to a higher level.

```
async.eachSeries(res, function (r, callback1) {

    let _id = r._id;
    let arr = r.campaignID;

    async.eachSeries(arr, function firstLevel (a, callback2) {

        let users = a.users;
        let id = a.id;
        let loop = Math.ceil(users / 1000);
        let limit = 0, offset = 0;

        // for loop is synchronous whereas mailjet is asynchronous -> usually bad idea to mix those two
        // instead try async.timesSeries()
        async.timesSeries(loop, function getSentMessages (n, callback3) {

            if (users > 1000) {
                limit = 1000;
                users -= limit;
            } else {
                limit = users;
            }
            console.log(n, limit, "limit", offset, "offset");

            var start = Date.now();
            while (Date.now() < start + 100) {} // this does nothing...

            // async.js doesn't flow well with Promises so request your resource with a callback function
            mailjet
                .get("messagesentstatistics")
                .request({ CampaignID: id, AllMessages: true, Limit: limit, Offset: offset })
                .request(function (err, result, body) {

                // stop everything if an error occurred; send the error back up
                if (err) return callback3(err);

                let data = result.body.Data;
                var loop = 0;

                async.eachSeries(data, secondLevel (jsonObj, callback4) {
                    let email = jsonObj.ToEmail;
                    jsonObj.retailer = r.retailer;
                    jsonObj.summary = 'f';
                    let tempObj = {};
                    tempObj[id] = jsonObj;
                    let options = { new: true };
                    let campId = id;
                    User.addCampaignResponse(email, campId, tempObj, options, function (err, results) {
                        // stop everything if an error occurred; send the error back up
                        if (err) return callback4(err);

                        console.log("added campaign response");

                        Campaign.updateResponse(_id, function (err, results2) {
                            // stop everything if an error occurred; send the error back up
                            if (err) return callback4(err);

                            console.log("updated campaign response");

                            callback4();
                        });
                    })
                }, callback3);

            }); // end of mailjet

            offset += limit;

        }, callback2); // end of async.timesSeries

    }, callback1); // end of async.eachOfSeries

}, function (err) {
    // if an error occurs anywhere, it should back here
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("doneeeeee");
});
```

Also it's always better to use meaningful variable and function names.

Comment: I can see you have put immense efforts in structuring the code and providing a solution that I suppose could help me out. But the code gives error for the inner most async saying "," is expected and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @MisterKartoot There was a small typo in my code. Check "edited..." link to see where. I'm not sure if that will resolve it. I'd also suggest you put `console.log` statements at different breakpoints to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplified corrected version of it

---

```
function secondLevel(value2, val, callback) {
    // ...
    User.addCampaignResponse(email, campId, tempObj, options, function (err, results) {
       if (err) {
          throw err;
       }

       Campaign.updateResponse(_id, function (err, results2) {
          // throw the error to the highest level if there is one
          if (err) throw err;

          // Finish the eachOfSeries if all is ok
          callback();
       });
    });
 }
```

---

```
function firstLevel(value1, i, callback) {
  // ...
  mailjet
    .get("messagesentstatistics")
    .request({
      // ...
    })
    .then((result) => {
      // ...
      async.eachOfSeries(data, secondLevel, function (err) {
        // throw the error to the highest level if there is one
        if (err) throw err;

        // Finish the eachOfSeries if all is ok
        callback();
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // throw the error to the highest level
      throw err;
    });
}
```

---

```
 //
 // Start of our program
 //
 async.eachOfSeries(res, function (value, camp, callback) {
     // ...
     async.eachOfSeries(arr, firstLevel, function (err) {
       // throw the error to the highest level if there is one
       if (!err) throw err;

       // Finish the eachOfSeries if all is ok
       callback();
     });
 },
 function (err) {
     if (err) {
        // Here we re done with an error
        // ...
        return;
     }

     // We did it, no, error
     // ...
 });
```

Comment: I tried to use this refactoring, it says arr is not defined, which means the firstlevel function cannot see arr.

Comment: So pass it as data

Comment: It says arr is undefined when tried to access inside the function.

Comment: You did declare it in top scope as `let arr = res[camp].campaignID;`. I bet you did a mistake when adapting my answer to your case. Look at it again, try to understand what I did and change the code you have.

Comment: This is what I have done. https://gist.github.com/ankurchavda/26330312c6b77c73c0206c2dd5310757

Comment: You did declare `function1` & `function2` outside the initial `async.eachOfSeries`. If you want it to work you have to declare `function1` & `function2` below `let arr = res[camp].campaignID;`. I can help more here you have everything to make it work, just look at it and try to figure it out. It's regular code, no special errors stack overflow can help you with

Comment: Ya so it got it working, https://gist.github.com/ankurchavda/26330312c6b77c73c0206c2dd5310757 .But still get an error at secondlevel function saying callback already called. So the refactoring didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Removed it, no success. Still gives the same error.

Comment: So you 'll have to find out by yourself. How to do it? Insert `console.log(...)` all the way down, you 'll see what is called and when. Then figure what happen at each step.

Comment: L67  this is `callback();` and not `callback1();` tho

Comment: Yeah have changed that. However, I did not get the part of using console.log() at the end.

Comment: I wouldn't throw your errors, but pass it to the callback i.e. `if (err) return callback(err);`. If you pass the error in the first argument of your callback, it will safely stop the current async function.